# Performance of union of date partitioned tables

Tags: google-bigquery

In my dataset, i have many date partitioned tables, one for each category. All of them have the same structure. They are small tables now, with 1500 rows each one. Querying any of them takes like 3.5 secs:

```
SELECT * FROM [dataset.table1] WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("YYYY-MM-DD") AND TIMESTAMP("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

(Job ID: bquijob_7e49a41d_1579405ac67)

Sometimes, i need to query results for two or more tables. When i try this, it takes a lot of time to execute. I have tried two approaches:

**Test 1: subqueries**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM [dataset.table1] 
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("YYYY-MM-DD") AND TIMESTAMP("YYYY-MM-DD")), 
(SELECT * FROM [dataset.table2] 
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("YYYY-MM-DD") AND TIMESTAMP("YYYY-MM-DD"))
```

Took 12.7 secs (Job ID: bquijob_6ce61e51_15794050134)

**Test 2: implicit union**

```
SELECT * FROM [dataset.table1], [dataset.table2] 
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("YYYY-MM-DD") AND TIMESTAMP("YYYY-MM-DD"))
```

Took 14 secs (Job ID: bquijob_669dc617_15793fdd09c)

Why are the so slow? Is there any way to improve the performance of this queries?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post a few job IDs maybe a google engineer will check it internally

Comment: Yes, if you can post the project ID and job ID I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Pentium10 and Hua Zhang. I have edited my question with the Job IDs.